# kendo react upload, how to perform a custom upload/remove using its corresponding events

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload, kendo-react-ui

i'm trying to implement a custom upload using the `@progress/kendo-react-upload component`

the upload should insert some metadata in the db morovere uploading the file, so i wouldn't use the `saveUrl` and `removeUrl` but to call the server during the adding e removing events

the `Upload` component has these properties:

```
<Upload
        autoUpload={false}
        onRemove={onRemove}
        onStatusChange={onStatusChange}
        defaultFiles={files}
      />
```

`autoupload=false`, because the file shouldn't be uploaded automatically when selected but when the upload button is pressed

in `defaultFiles` there are previously uploaded files that i want to show in the list (to permit the user to deleted these files from the server eventually, these file are correctly identified into the event `onRemove`)

```
const onRemove = (event: any) => {
    const fileToRemove = event.affectedFiles;
    //...call the server to remove (removing the file and its metadata in the db)
};
```

new selected files are correctly listed in the:

```
const onStatusChange = (event: UploadOnStatusChangeEvent) => {
     const readyToUpload = event.affectedFiles.filter(
       (item: UploadFileInfo)   => item.status == UploadFileStatus.Uploading
     );

     //...call the server to upload the file and add some metadata into a databae
  };
```

how to prevent that `saveUrl` and `removeUrl` are automatically invoked  when thes files are added or removed from the component and to manage the upload in the corresponding events